# What is if [ ! -f ] in shell script(grub.cfg)?

Tags: shell

I can understand **if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]** which just checks the existence of the file "/etc/bashrc". but what is  "**if [ ! -f ]**". This line I came across at grub.cfg.

This may be a simple syntax but I couldn't get the answer by simply googling, as its not an usual syntax.

Thanks

Comment: The command `[ ! -f ]` checks if `-f` is the empty string. (It is not.).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `[` can be found at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html; the relevant section being:

```
If $1 is '!', exit true if $2 is null, false if $2 is not null.
```

Since the first argument is `!` and the second argument is not the null string, the command returns false (non-zero).

Usually, this is an error, probably caused by a failure to properly quote a variable.  At some point, the intent was probably to do something like `if [ ! -f $filename ]`, and somewhere in the build chain the variable was the null string and that test expanded to `if [ ! -f ]`.